# what I am meant to do with a github-based bugfix? (python-django on Win OS)

Tags: python, django, git, github

Not used to working collaboratively!  I am gradually learning the mysteries of Git, but how you use github is still beyond me.

This relates to a bug with Django and Selenium as documented here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21227

This takes us to this page on github: https://github.com/django/django/commit/08c9ab5a0f564a3ac7803e6a97fae855f2e0524e

I "manually" added the new line ("refresh") to the file ...\admin\tests.py, and this seems to stop some of the ConnectionResetErrors occurring... but I don't know how to use this commit on github: in particular, the other file shown here, tests\view_tests\tests\test_i18n.py, doesn't exist, nor its path.

Am I meant somehow to "git pull" from github?  And sort of replace my django file structure under "site-packages"?

I have a book on github (yes, an entire book!) and I will read it as soon as I can, promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its core, GitHub is "just" a hosting service for Git repositories. You can clone the Django repository (`git clone https://github.com/django/django.git`) and then checkout that specific commit (`git checkout 08c9ab5a0f564a3ac7803e6a97fae855f2e0524e`). You can install it with `pip install -e https://github.com/django/django.git` (to put it in site-packages) or `pip install -e /path/to/django` (if you want it somewhere else).

On top of that, GitHub has tons and tons of features that make the life of a collaborating developer a lot easier.